# Implementing HDIV on a Login Page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, hdiv

I'm implementing HDIV in Spring MVC and I have trouble in the Login Page.
Since HDIV would require the use of the `form` tag

(like: `<form:form action="${contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" method="post">`),
my app would throw an exception because I did not specify the `modelAttribute`:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute`

Can anyone give clarity to this concern? Is there any other way to implement HDIV on a login page? Or is there a way to implement HDIV without using `<form:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [HDIV Spring MVC Showcase](https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv-spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp) project, you do not have to use Spring's form tag in the Login Page.

In addition, you have to put `/j_spring_security_check` as a start page in the `hdiv-config.xml`:

```
        <hdiv:startPages method="post">/j_spring_security_check</hdiv:startPages>
```

Do not worry about the editable validations because they work even if the url is a `startPage`.